# ActiveJdbc Validação Composta

Tags: java, orm

Necessito fazer uma validação composta no ORM ActiveJdbc e não estou encontrando nada na documentação. Algo do tipo, extends da classe ValidatorAdapter, mas não estou encontrando material para usar como exemplo.

Basicamente:

```
public class Competencia extends Model{

  static{
    validateWith(new UniquenessValidator("mes", "ano")).message("O número de documento já existe");
  }

}
```

Consegui fazer (peguei de um amigo) o Uniqueness com um campo, mas estou com dificuldades para fazer para dois campos. Como posso contornar esta dificuldade, será que alguém tem algum exemplo semelhante?

Comment: Eu acho que você vai ter que escrever seu próprio [`Validator`](http://javalite.io/validations#custom-validators) baseado no [`UniquenessValidator`](https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/blob/master/activejdbc/src/main/java/org/javalite/activejdbc/validation/UniquenessValidator.java). Por exemplo, recebendo um vararg `String... attributes` e modificando o método `validate` para considerar todos os atributos recebidos na consulta. Se você for fazer isso verifique que a tabela está devidamente indexada ou a solução irá sofrer devido à _performance_ da consulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package #.#.#.#.#.dominio.validacoes;

import org.javalite.activejdbc.Base;
import org.javalite.activejdbc.Model;
import org.javalite.activejdbc.ModelDelegate;
import org.javalite.activejdbc.validation.ValidatorAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

public class UKValidator extends ValidatorAdapter {

    public static final String CODIGO = "V0001";
    public static final String DESCRICAO = "Restrição de chave única violada";

    private final String[] attributes;

    private UKValidator() {
        attributes = null;
    }

    public UKValidator(String... attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Model model) {
        StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" AND ");
        List<Object> params = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String attribute : attributes) {
            sj.add(attribute + " = ?");
            params.add(model.get(attribute));
        }

        Long count = Base.count(ModelDelegate.metaModelOf(model.getClass()).getTableName(),
                sj.toString(),
                params.toArray());

        if (count > 0) {
            model.addError(CODIGO, String.format("%s: %s", DESCRICAO, toString()));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(attributes);
    }
}
```

Serve?

Comment: Existe uma forma de chamar a validação APENAS no create? Considerando que estou em edição, não precisaria validar novamente.